# Slider with Multiple Handle and Background Color for content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am trying to work with Jquery UI slider where I can have multiple handles:

```
$(function () {
        var handlers = [25, 50, 75];
        $("#slider").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            values: handlers,
            slide: function (evt, ui) {
                for (var i = 0, l = ui.values.length; i < l; i++) {
                    if (i !== l - 1 && ui.values[i] > ui.values[i + 1]) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if (i === 0 && ui.values[i] < ui.values[i - 1]) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Please note that one handler can't overlap and I will need to set the handler dynamically on load, and save the handler positions on change.

The thing that i am trying to accomplish is to color the ui-content betweent the handler to different colors. I have attached the an Image.

[image: Slider]

Please advice if this is possible.

Comment: Setting the handler's dynamically on load is handled by jQuery UI and the code you provide above will work with dynamic values.  It also takes care of not letting the handlers overlap.

Coloring the content between the handlers is not something that's built into jQuery UI but it can be done.  The best idea I can come up with at the moment is to create absolutely positioned divs with the appropriate `background-color` and dynamically place them as the handles are moved.  I'll see if I can come up with a concrete implementation later.  Here's a starting point - http://jsfiddle.net/LLfWd/.

Comment: thx. I would love to see the concrete implementation! Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possibility would be to set the slider background to a CSS gradient and to update the gradient stops in code when the slider values change:

```
$(function () {
    // the code belows assume the colors array is exactly one element bigger 
    // than the handlers array.
    var handlers = [25, 50, 75];
    var colors = ["#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff", "#00ffff"];
    updateColors(handlers);

    $("#slider").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        values: handlers,
        slide: function (evt, ui) {
            updateColors(ui.values);
        }
    });

    function updateColors(values) {
        var colorstops = colors[0] + ", "; // start left with the first color
            for (var i=0; i< values.length; i++) {
                colorstops += colors[i] + " " + values[i] + "%,";
                colorstops += colors[i+1] + " " + values[i] + "%,";
            }
            // end with the last color to the right
            colorstops += colors[colors.length-1];

            /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
            var css = '-webkit-linear-gradient(left,' + colorstops + ')';
            $('#slider').css('background-image', css);
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LLfWd/60/

This code works for chrome and safari. My guess is you just have to generate multiple gradient strings (for -moz-linear-gradient, -ms-linear-gradient, etc...) the way I did it for -webkit-linear-gradient here.

Answer (score 2):

(⌐■_■)  Hello there, my code attached below implements (i) 3 JQuery UI Slider handles which means 4 ranges, (ii) non-collision of range values, (iii) coloring of ranges, (iv) title tooltip on handle and (v) display of range values. Please note that I am using an old JQuery version. Also, it has a pattern which means it can likely be re-coded to support >=4 handles elegantly as well.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test Slider</title>

    <link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <style>
    div.demo { padding: 10px !important; };
    </style>
    <div class="demo">

        <p>
            <label>% Style:</label>
            <input type="text" id="weightage_style" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
            <br />
            <label>% Design:</label>
            <input type="text" id="weightage_design" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
            <br />
            <label>% Correctness:</label>
            <input type="text" id="weightage_correctness" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
            <br />
            <label>% Others:</label>
            <input type="text" id="weightage_others" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
            <br />
        </p>

        <div id="weightage_slider" style="font-size:12px;width:300px;"></div>

    </div>

    <script>
        $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider({ 
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            orientation: "horizontal", 
            step: 1, 
            values: [ 10, 40, 90 ], // set three handles
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                // NOTE: during slide, the following sequence occurs: (i) change ui.value (ii) call this function (iii) move the slider handle

                // these four lines update the display of handle ranges
                $( "#weightage_style" ).val( "0" + " - " + $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 0) );
                $( "#weightage_design" ).val( $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 0) + " - " + $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 1) );
                $( "#weightage_correctness" ).val( $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 1) + " - " + $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 2) );
                $( "#weightage_others" ).val( $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 2) + " - " + "100" );

                if ( ui.handle == $( "#weightage_slider_0" ).get(0) ) {
                    if(ui.values[ 0 ] >= ui.values[ 1 ]){
                        $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 0, ui.values[ 1 ]); // triggers change event
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        // handle-0 will move
                        // update display of colored handle ranges
                        $( "#weightage_slider_a" ).css('left', '0%');
                        $( "#weightage_slider_a" ).css('width', (ui.values[ 0 ] + '%'));
                        $( "#weightage_slider_b" ).css('left', (ui.values[ 0 ] + '%'));
                        $( "#weightage_slider_b" ).css('width', ((ui.values[1] - ui.values[0]) + '%'));
                    }
                }

                if ( ui.handle == $( "#weightage_slider_1" ).get(0) ) {
                    if(ui.values[ 1 ] <= ui.values[ 0 ]){
                        $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 1, ui.values[ 0 ]); // triggers change event
                        return false;
                    }else if(ui.values[ 1 ] >= ui.values[ 2 ]){
                        $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 1, ui.values[ 2 ]); // triggers change event
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        // handle-1 will move
                        // update display of colored handle ranges
                        $( "#weightage_slider_b" ).css('left', (ui.values[ 0 ] + '%'));
                        $( "#weightage_slider_b" ).css('width', ((ui.values[1] - ui.values[0]) + '%'));
                        $( "#weightage_slider_c" ).css('left', (ui.values[ 1 ] + '%'));
                        $( "#weightage_slider_c" ).css('width', ((ui.values[2] - ui.values[1]) + '%'));
                    }
                }

                if ( ui.handle == $( "#weightage_slider_2" ).get(0) ) {
                    if(ui.values[ 2 ] <= ui.values[ 1 ]){
                        $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 2, ui.values[ 1 ]); // triggers change event
                        return false;
                    } else{
                        // handle-2 will move
                        // update display of colored handle ranges
                        $( "#weightage_slider_c" ).css('left', (ui.values[ 1 ] + '%'));
                        $( "#weightage_slider_c" ).css('width', ((ui.values[2] - ui.values[1]) + '%'));
                        $( "#weightage_slider_d" ).css('left', (ui.values[ 2 ] + '%'));
                        $( "#weightage_slider_d" ).css('width', ((100 - ui.values[2]) + '%'));
                    }
                }
            }, 
            change: function( event, ui ) {
                // because slide event has function that changes handles' value programmatically, the following is necessary

                // these four lines update the display of handle ranges
                $( "#weightage_style" ).val( "0" + " - " + $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 0) );
                $( "#weightage_design" ).val( $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 0) + " - " + $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 1) );
                $( "#weightage_correctness" ).val( $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 1) + " - " + $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 2) );
                $( "#weightage_others" ).val( $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 2) + " - " + "100" );

                // update display of colored handle ranges
                $( "#weightage_slider_a" ).css('left', '0%');
                $( "#weightage_slider_a" ).css('width', (ui.values[ 0 ] + '%'));
                $( "#weightage_slider_b" ).css('left', (ui.values[ 0 ] + '%'));
                $( "#weightage_slider_b" ).css('width', ((ui.values[1] - ui.values[0]) + '%'));
                $( "#weightage_slider_c" ).css('left', (ui.values[ 1 ] + '%'));
                $( "#weightage_slider_c" ).css('width', ((ui.values[2] - ui.values[1]) + '%'));
                $( "#weightage_slider_d" ).css('left', (ui.values[ 2 ] + '%'));
                $( "#weightage_slider_d" ).css('width', ((100 - ui.values[2]) + '%'));
            }
        });

        // label each slider handle
        $( "#weightage_slider > a" ).each(function(index){
            $(this).attr('id', 'weightage_slider_' + index);
            $(this).attr('title', 'slider handle ' + index);    
        });

        // the following four div tags result in the display of colored handle ranges
        // the following left attributes and width attributes should be consistent with slider initialization - values array
        $('#weightage_slider').append("<div id='weightage_slider_a' class='ui-slider-range' style='left:0%;width:10%;background-color:#41d862;'></div>");
        $('#weightage_slider').append("<div id='weightage_slider_b' class='ui-slider-range' style='left:10%;width:30%;background-color:#41b7d8;'></div>");
        $('#weightage_slider').append("<div id='weightage_slider_c' class='ui-slider-range' style='left:40%;width:50%;background-color:#d841b7;'></div>");
        $('#weightage_slider').append("<div id='weightage_slider_d' class='ui-slider-range' style='left:90%;width:10%;background-color:#d86241;'></div>");

        // these four lines display the initial handle ranges
        $( "#weightage_style" ).val( "0" + " - " + $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 0) );
        $( "#weightage_design" ).val( $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 0) + " - " + $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 1) );
        $( "#weightage_correctness" ).val( $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 1) + " - " + $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 2) );
        $( "#weightage_others" ).val( $( "#weightage_slider" ).slider('values', 2) + " - " + "100" );
    </script>

</body>
```

Bug: If handles are dragged to most left, they become "stuck", so you might want to have a reset button to restore handles' position.