# Limit range slider in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, anythingslider, rangeslider

I am new to angular js.
I would like to implement as following.
Devide `100%` into multiple options(dynamic).

Example: 
`RGB` colors, user can using our slider set `Red-20%`, `Green-30%`, `Blue-50%`(balance)
Gender `male-40%`, `Female-60%` remaining balance.

If user set male to `45%` automatically female set to remaining balance `55%` with the same slider different color.

Finance share amount between people.
http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/#samples in that multiple range slider 
[Slider with Multiple Handle and Background Color for content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485075/slider-with-multiple-handle-and-background-color-for-content)

Can you suggest any one how to achieve using which slider module suit to me ?

Answer (score 0):

Here in CodePen you can see an example of multi-range slider:

http://codepen.io/anandthakker/pen/marlo

Example of usage:

**HTML**

```
<slider model="probs" property="p" step=".05"></slider>
```

**MODEL**

```
$scope.probs = [ p: .1, p: .5,  p: .4]
```

and also a Plunker with a similar 'component':

http://plnkr.co/edit/fb9UD14AOoQqkgKxckrg?p=info